# Nullable generic key in EF POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Consider a customisable data model wherein the keys of your models are generic. A model such as the following:

```
public class Model<TKey, TUserKey> {
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey NullableUserId { get; set; } // ?
}
```

Of course, the following doesn't work as `TUserKey` could be a reference *or* value type at this stage (that's the point):

```
public virtual TUserKey? NullableUserId { get; set; }
```

The obvious way to combat this is to have a generic layout such as the following:

```
public class Model<TKey, TUserKey, TOptionalUserKey> {
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual TOptionalUserKey NullableUserId { get; set; }
}
```

This would mean that you could instantiate it as `<int, string, string>` or `<string, int, int?>` just as a couple of examples.

Question is - Can I avoid having to do the latter and having more generic type params? In my real-life model I have 2 key types that could be nullable, the optional variant of `TKey` and the optional variant of `TUserKey`, and if possible I would like to handle this "magically" rather than rely on the user to pass in nullable variants of their keys.

NB. EF's `.Property(..).IsOptional()` wouldn't work here as it would mean the model isn't representative of the data and / or that the implementer would need to remember it in their model builder override.

NB2. A further wrapper class for creation that would detect if class or value, then create it won't work either, as it's this class that will be mapped directly to a `DbSet` and we need to pass this around.

Comment: Try setting it to nullable on the property like this. public virtual Nullable<TOptionalUserKey> NullableUserId {get;set;}

Comment: @StephenBrickner Thanks, but as I put in the question already that won't work as it may or may not be a value type.

Comment: @Fabjan It's already nullable? There is no point? That's not what I'm trying to do. People can pass in either a reference _or_ value type as the generic parameter, I need to handle both to be nullable.

Comment: @Fabjan I believe he said that the generic (T) needs to support both reference and value types.

Comment: What is the type on your database field for this property? You could technically just remove the type param altogether and make that field a string. If it is an object serialize it to json before saving. In either case you would have to try parse it out to figure out what type you are dealing with.

Comment: @StephenBrickner I'm really not sure you understand the problem. This model is the database model which will be used to generate the database. Hence why the EF `.IsOptional` method is not applicable either, it would require further configuration outside of the model which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can come up with quickly (since C# doesn't offer some of C++'s template features that would let you do this in one class) is to have two generic classes:

```
public class Model<TKey, TUserKey> where TUserKey : struct
{
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey? NullableUserId { get; set; }   
}

public class Model2<TKey, TUserKey> where TUserKey : class
{
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey NullableUserId { get; set; }
}
```

You can't use the wrong key type (due to the constraints), and you get the nullable behavior in both, but it's not as elegant as I'd like.

Comment: +1 for a different solution than what I tried, thanks! Obviously the point of this question is to make it elegant, as it's not really an issue per se, the extra generic types can just be added. It's just horrible :(

Comment: Agreed - but without partial template specialization a la C++, I don't think there's a better route.

Comment: That's my fear exactly! :( The only other (slightly cleaner way) is as I put in "NB2", have a class above it that creates the generics based on whether the argument is a value type or not, but still boils down to having 2 models (although one is an abstraction of the other) and reducing the elegance of the solution. Sad times!